# MongoDB TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined [Node JS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to insert data in mongoDB database/collection using node js and the code is as follows.

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
async function triggerApi(){
var post = {username: "bingo", message: "this is a test"};
const uri = "mongodb+srv://localhost:27017/blog?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
        await MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db){
            db.collection("posts").insertOne(post, function(err, result){
                console.log("Inserted post data");
                db.close();
            });
        });
}
```

When I run the aforementioned code snippet I am getting the following error:

> /Users/somdipdey/repos/project1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:691
> throw error;
>
> ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

How to fix this and run the code properly?

Comment: check error parameter before any operation `if (err) console.log(err);`

Comment: It seems you are using await with callback together. Try to run Mongo.client without `await`

Comment: @turivishal getting this error: MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld

Comment: @CássioLacerda it is still happening without the await.

Comment: try only in url `mongodb://localhost:27017/blog` and make sure you have started mongodb database server in same host.

Comment: @turivishal tried just the MongoDB://localhost:27017 but the same error happening. btw what do u mean by "have started mongodb database server in same host". I am new to mongodb.

Comment: See installation and setup guide in [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/) for particular OS. i would suggest you to just clear what is mongodb and how its work internally.